# IndexedWidgetBuilder, how does it know the index?

Tags: dart, flutter

This is mostly a conceptual question as I'm new to Dart and I guess I'm not understanding the semantics of the language here.

In IndexedWidgetBuilder,

```
Widget IndexedWidgetBuilder (
BuildContext context,
int index
)
```

who exactly is giving a value to index?

When this "thing" is used, for example:

```
itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    blablabla
},
```

"context" and "i" are never initialized and they magically have a value. Who is defining this value and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexedWidgetBuilder` is a `typedef` that defines a function that takes a `BuildContext` and an `int`, and returns a `Widget`.

```
/// Signature for a function that creates a widget for a given index, e.g., in a
/// list.
///
/// Used by [ListView.builder] and other APIs that use lazily-generated widgets.
typedef Widget IndexedWidgetBuilder(BuildContext context, int index);
```

So, when defining `itemBuilder` you are providing the Widget with a function that it can call, when it wants to build an item. When the Widget is building itself it will call this function many times to build each of its children. Simplistically, it may call this function with i=0, then 1, then 2, etc.

If your Widget only has 3 children, it would be easier to just pass then as a List, but if your Widget has a thousand children this would be inefficient - and this is where the builder comes in. The Widget will try to only call the itemBuilder function for the child widgets that it actually needs, and not for any that are, say, off the top or bottom of the screen.

So, to answer your question, the Widget passes the context and i to your itemBuilder function when it calls it (typically multiple times) to build some or all of its children. `i` represents the `i`th child, so that your builder function knows which child it is being asked to build.

**Edit**

The dartdoc of `IndexedWidgetBuilder` says that it is used by `ListView.builder`.

The dartdoc of `ListView.builder` says

> Providing a non-null itemCount improves the ability of the [ListView]
>   to estimate the maximum scroll extent. The itemBuilder callback will
>   be called only with indices **greater than or equal to zero and less
>   than itemCount**. The itemBuilder should actually create the widget
>   instances when called.

The `ListView.builder` named constructor constructs a `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`, passing in the itemBuilder as builder.

It gets used in the `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`'s build method, here:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, int index) {
    assert(builder != null);
    if (index < 0 || (childCount != null && index >= childCount))
      return null;
    Widget child = builder(context, index); // <- your callback is called
    if (child == null)
      return null;
    if (addRepaintBoundaries)
      child = new RepaintBoundary.wrap(child, index);
    if (addAutomaticKeepAlives)
      child = new AutomaticKeepAlive(child: child);
    return child;
  }
```

So, `index` comes from the `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`'s build method. You could keep walking backwards to see who calls that.

Comment: "the Widget passes the context and i to your itemBuilder function"

I understand that, but I still don't understand **where**. I can't find the code where this is done, it's not in ListView, it isn't in any of the classes it inherits from. For all I know this i could start from 0, it could start from 1, it could start from 1000 and go backwards, it has to be defined somewhere.

I'm not very comfortable in a language that does magic invisible stuff. I don't care about the itemBuilder itself, I care about how easy/difficult/possible it is to find the source code of the stuff I am using.

Comment: See the edit to the answer that drills back a few layers to show how the callback is called.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, I understood more. (Still I don't like this at all)